# how to add a wait in time in a for ..of?

Tags: javascript

I am building a code that allows me to wait for a promise to be resolved to advance to the next, I am also adding a separate time for each wait, but only the first loop is printed, if I remove the wait in seconds this works well.

in play code I get this error, in other editors I simply print the first loop

```
error: Infinity loop on line 8, char 6. You can increase loop timeout in settings.
```

https://playcode.io/309050?tabs=console&script.js&output

in the stackoverflow code editor if the code works but in my project or in another code editor they do not work

```js
 const urls = [
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2',
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3'
    ];
    
    async function getTodos() {
      for (const [idx, url] of urls.entries()) {
        const todo = await fetch(url);
        console.log(`Received Todo ${idx+1}:`, todo);
         await wait(1000)
      }
    
      console.log('Finished!');
    }
    
    getTodos();
    
    function wait(ms) {
      return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
    }
```

Comment: `but in my project or in another code editor they do not work` What happens?  What error(s) are you getting?  Be more specific on what it is doing.

Comment: just tried it and it says "error: Infinity loop on line 8, char 6. You can increase loop timeout in settings.". This definitely isn't a standard JS error, seems to be something to do with the site you're hosting the code on.

Comment: Yes, it's just the editor your using trying to protect you from infinite loops.  You can increase this in the settings, the cog icon, and then you will have `Loop Protection Timeout.`  Just increase this, the default was only 100ms,  1/10th of a second.. :)

Comment: the code works fine in the runnable snippet above. As others have said, I think it's just an extra warning in the editor you're using.

Answer (score 3):

Some online code playgrounds, [like CodePen](https://blog.codepen.io/2014/12/16/infinite-loop-protection-round-two/), have built-in infinite-loop detection. This is to prevent the UI from freezing in the event that you accidentally write an infinite loop while scratch coding. This is usually achieved by statically analyzing your code. Because of this, it cannot tell what your code actually does at runtime (and it may not be infinite at all). The best they can do is guess based on structure.

In your case, your code editor thinks that you're doing an infinite loop. There's probably settings in your editor to disable that.

Comment: thank you, try the code in production and it works well, it was the problem of online publishers